# share audio from raspberry 3

Tags: audio

I connected Raspberry 3 (OpenELEC 7.0.1.) to the projector (HDMI). I would like to play back movies from an external HD connected to Raspberry, but I need to share audio (wifi or bluethoth) to AV Receiver YAMAHA RX-S600.

Is it possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not connect the cable to the device.

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Plug the HDMI cable from the Rasperry Pi into one of the inputs of your receiver, select that input, and plug the HDMI output of your receiver into the projector. The receiver will play back the audio signal sent down the HDMI cable along with the video signal.